# When I use the Kaminari in Rails, the structure repeated in view

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, kaminari, pagination

[image: the paginate in view]

[image: structrue in view]

In my controller:

```
@xxxs = XXX.page(params[:page] || 1).per(10)
```

In my view:

```
<div class="turn_page>
  <%= paginate @xxxs, window: 2 %>
</div>
```

Why the content in the end of the font is repeated again, but inside the  tag, only the link has no html content

Comment: May be this issue is generated due to CSS conflicts